# Execute powershell script using psexec

Tags: powershell, psexec

I am trying to execute PowerShell script on 10 computers on same $env:userprofile path using psexec.But it won't work. If i specify path like "c:\Users\bob\" , it works. Below script is not working.

```
psexec -u domain\bob -p password -h -d cmd /c powershell.exe -Command "(New-Object System.Net.Webclient).DownloadFile('http://x.x.x.x/1.exe','$env:userprofile\1.exe')"
```

Comment: your script has a typo: $ev:HOMEPATH\1.exe should be $env:HOMEPATH\1.exe

Comment: Also homepath will return \users\user not C:\users\user

Comment: Can i use $env:userprofile ?

Comment: Don't see why not

Comment: You can't use variables in single quoted strings in PowerShell. `DownloadFile('http://x.x.x.x/1.exe', $env:userprofile+'\1.exe')` might work

Comment: Why not use `powershell remoting`? Like `Invoke-Command`?